# What is the most efficient way to arrange images radially using javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, image

I have been racking my brain on how to make this work.  I can find no examples of this and actually no previous questions.  Basically I have a 121 thumbnail images (with the exact same dimensions), arrange them in a grid with gutters and I want to take the first image and place it in the center.  (this allows for an 11x11 image grid)  Then I would like to take each next image and begin to arrange them around the center image using the next closest available vacant location to the center image until all used up.  It is assumed the list of images will be gotten from an array object.  What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: This is called "fill a matrix in spiral order". Try googling that, there are lots of solutions.

Comment: It may not even be relevant, but i was intrigued by your question and hacked together a jQuery script to do it - just in case anyone is interested, i'll leave it here: http://jsfiddle.net/PxLAV/2/

Comment: Thank you soo much for your contribution Andreas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely not the most efficient way of solving this, but I wanted to play with it:

You could iterate over all the points in your grid, calculate their distances to the center point and then sort the points by this distance. The advantage over the algorithmic solutions is that you can use all sorts of distance functions:

```
// Setup constants
var arraySize = 11;
var centerPoint = {x:5, y:5};

// Calculate the Euclidean Distance between two points
function distance(point1, point2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point1.x - point2.x, 2) + Math.pow(point1.y - point2.y, 2));
}

// Create array containing points with distance values
var pointsWithDistances = [];
for (var i=0; i<arraySize; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<arraySize; j++) {
        var point = {x:i, y:j};
        point.distance = distance(centerPoint, point);
        pointsWithDistances.push(point);
    }
}

// Sort points by distance value
pointsWithDistances.sort(function(point1, point2) {
    return point1.distance == point2.distance ? 0 : point1.distance < point2.distance ? -1 : 1;
});
```

The resulting `pointsWithDistances` array will look like this:

```
[
    {x:5, y:5, distance:0},
    {x:4, y:5, distance:1},
    {x:5, y:4, distance:1},
    ...
    {x:4, y:4, distance:1.4142135623730951},
    {x:4, y:6, distance:1.4142135623730951},
    ...
    {x:3, y:5, distance:2},
    ...
]
```

By iterating over the array in this order you are effectively filling the grid from the center outwards.

[image: Using Euclidean Distances]

(Thanks for Andreas Carlbom's idea how to display this structure.)

Check out the difference to using Rectilinear Distances:

```
// Rectilinear Distance between two points
function distance(point1, point2) {
    return Math.abs(point1.x - point2.x) + Math.abs(point1.y - point2.y);
}
```

[image: Using Rectilinear Distances]

For the shell-like structure of the algorithmic approaches you can use the Maximum Metric:

```
// 'Maximum Metric' Distance between two points
function distance(point1, point2) {
    return Math.max(Math.abs(point1.x - point2.x), Math.abs(point1.y - point2.y));
}
```

[image: Using 'Maximum Metric' distances]

You can play with the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/green/B3cF8/

Comment: You answered this question just how I hoped someone would, thank you!  Perhaps someone will show us an even faster method, but in the meantime, how would I go about adding gutters in between each div since the positions are calculated by absolute position in your examples?  Adding margin via CSS doesn't affect the positioning of the div's around it...

Comment: Yes, the divs in the jsFiddle code are absolutely positioned and size tile size is fixed in the code. I have extracted a `tileSize` variable and updated the example, have a look.

Comment: Thank you for your work, this got me totally set in the correct direction!  Great advise!

Comment: Yes: http://jsfiddle.net/green/e2gFx. If you don't need the tiles to fit without any gaps you can drop all the `Math.ceil`/`Math.floor` calls.

Comment: I have been having issues trying to center the middle div (outlined in red) in the viewport when you click on the gear, but I wish to have this div centered in the viewport automatically on page load.  The secondary issue is when moving through the array and hitting the gear... it centers another area of the array due to the way overscroll works and I want to figure out a way to overcome this so every time the gear is clicked it brings you to the center div.  Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/virtuapete/QVQ5r/1/

Comment: Well, that's a [different story](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997024/how-to-implement-a-multi-directional-scroll-follow-effect)...