# How to implement a multi-directional scroll-follow effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, rotation

I have an array of divs which are dimensionally larger than its container (parent).  I have overflow set to hidden on the container and call the JQuery Overscroll on the map to give it the feel of an iPhone http://www.azoffdesign.com/overscroll.

I am having an issue tackling how to implement a tracking arrow for when the user scrolls the array and the center div (home) goes into overflow out-of-sight.  When the user scrolls "home" out of view into the overflow region, I would like an arrow to appear at the inside edge of the container and follow it around the edge wherever it goes out of view.  It makes sense to me to use an image for the arrow, then rotate it so it points in the correct direction as "home" gets moved around.

Here is my fiddle with the base work > http://jsfiddle.net/virtuapete/QVQ5r/1/

So there are 3 elements to this to make it work properly... the image following "home' as it moves around in overflow, rotation of the image with respect to where home is (so the arrow always points to "home" and then simply hiding the arrow once home becomes visible within the container.

I am pretty sure I have seen this effect before and to begin tackling the issue I started looking up scroll follow techniques since that would be a close 1-dimensional example of this concept.  Kind of like a multi-directional scroll follow almost.  I have reached the point where I have completely confused myself now and I am def not strong enough in my skills to meld diff code snippets I have found into the desired result yet!

I found a jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/hj57k ) of something that could be along the lines of what I want, without the div following the object (in that example the cursor) once it has left the container boundaries.  Any help would be amazing as i am just stuck on how to get going... getting the div to follow the object around the sides would be a great start and I could probably take it from there...

Comment: Maybe a better way to solve the problem is thinking about a div (#2) positioned over another div (#1) in the container where div #2's movement is constrained to within the container's edge's??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/green/F8gd4/ or http://jsfiddle.net/green/GpG3U/.

Comment: Your layout looked too familiar ;)

Comment: This is a very good work!  How to get that arrow to move around the edges of the container though instead of staying stationary is the goal... and the part I am fuzziest about!  Yes the layout is great, thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is updated fiddle for multi directional scrolling.
Just add four line javascript like this

```
$(".container").overscroll({
    direction: 'auto'
});
```

[Jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/as88425/wwn0cf3q/)